# Can I patent my invention which is just an enhancement to an already patented device?

Tags: india, patents

Can I claim patent for my invention which is a little upgraded version of already patented devices. Moreover, I use same patented devices in my invention and add new functionalities to it. Is it worth patenting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not if it is "just" an advancement.

Improvements to processes, machines, manufactures, or compositions of matter, are patentable but only *if* they are new and useful, and non-obvious (among other requirements like adequate disclosure etc.)

35 USC 101-103, 112

Comment: Good answer. This is to prevent things like changing a brush to having a rubber handle and taking credit.

Comment: Almost everything is an improvement on something else. "Just an enhancement" could be huge commercially and very novel and non-obvious. Or not. Not enough information in the question to judge.